# Inheritance: why is there a difference in behaviour between inherited and supplied variables?

Tags: c++, inheritance

For example, in this piece of code, if `line [a]` is commented out, the output is 0.

> **inh2.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        int x;
        A() { x = 10; }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        int x;  // <--------- [a]
        B() { x = 0; }
};

int main() {
    A* ab = new B;
    cout << ab->x << endl;
}
```

> results from gcc

```
$ g++ inh2.cpp
$ ./a.out
10
$
```

I have two questions:

1. How does `ab->x` resolve to `10` in the above case? The object is of type `class B`, and thus should value to `0`.
2. Why does commenting `Line [a]` change the behaviour of the code? My reasoning is that `x` would have anyways been inherited, which should result in same behaviour.

---

My reasoning for Q #1 above:

- `ab` points to the memory location of an object of `class B`. It is a physical object in the sense that all the variables with their values are assigned memory.
- Variable `x` within this object stores value `0`.
- When `ab->x` is done, ab tells us the memory location of the object, and we go look inside it to find that x is 0. So we should print 0.

Where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is of type `B`, but you are assigning it as a pointer to an `A`, and therefore it is using the `x` defined on A (as when we're dealing with a pointer to A, we don't know that `B` even exists, even though that's what you allocated).
2. When you comment out the line, during the construction phase, `A`s constructor is called first, then `B`s constructor, which sets `x` (in its base class) to 0.  There is only one `x` at this point, and Bs constructor is called last.

Comment: Regarding #1, at runtime, it is known that the object is of type `B`, so shouldn't it resolve to 0?

Comment: @Lazer, known by whom?  We know it *is* a B, but the pointer we have is to an A, and that is what will be used.  To test this, add a new member to B, `int y;`.  Now do `ab->y`.  You'll get a compiler error as `y` is not a member of `A`.

Comment: `ab` points to the memory location of an object of `class B`. It is a physical object in the sense that all the variables with their values are assigned memory and are present. Variable `x` within this object stores value `0`. When `ab->x` is done, ab tells us the memory location of the object, and we go look inside it to find that x is `0`. So we should print `0`. Not sure what I am missing here? [we = compiler]

Comment: @Lazer, yes you're right - but you're working with a pointer to `A`, and so the compiler is not even considering `B`.

Comment: There are two variables at play here. `A::x` and `B::x`. If `p` is a pointer to `A`, then `p->x` refers to `A::x`. If it is a pointer to `B`, then `p->x` refers to `B::x` and `p->A::x` refers to `A::x`. There is no way to access `B::x` given only a pointer to `A` since there is no guarantee in general that there is even a `B`.

Comment: @Lazer: No, runtime polymorphism in C++ only applies to virtual functions. Not to variables.

Answer (score 1):

Making a some small modifications:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int x;
    A()
        :x(10)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int x;  // <--------- [a]
    B()
        :A()
        ,x(0)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* ab = new B;
    cout << "ab->x: " << ab->x << endl;
    cout << "ab->A::x " << ab->A::x << endl;

    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(ab);
    cout << "b->x: " << b->x << endl;
    cout << "b->A::x " << b->A::x << endl;
    cout << "b->B::x " << b->B::x << endl;
}
```

This gives you:

```
A
10
B
0
ab->x: 10
ab->A::x 10
b->x: 0
b->A::x 10
b->B::x 0
```

This demonstrates that:

- `ab->x` refers to `A::x` because `ab` is of type `A*` and there is no such thing as a `virtual` variable. If you want polymorphism, you'll have to write a `virtual int get_x() const` method.
- `B::x` hides `A::x`. This is a bad idea and should be avoided. Consider using a more meaningful name for your member variables and establish whether you can reuse the base class's variable before introducing a new one.
- Casting to a `B*` allows you access to `B`'s members as well as `A`'s. This should be self-explanatory.