# Does inheritance actually result in the members of a class to be 'inherited'?

Tags: c++, inheritance

From [an answer on **Inheritance: why is there a difference in behaviour between inherited and supplied variables?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665480/113124), I understand that the below code prints `0` because there is only one copy of `x`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        int x;
        A() { x = 10; }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B() { x = 0; }
};

int main() {
    A* ab = new B;
    cout << ab->x << endl; // prints 0
}
```

But does this not go against the very meaning of inheritance?

I coded `class B` to interit publicly from `class A`, and I expected it to **inherit a copy of member variable `x`**, which should have resulted in `ab->x` printing value `10`.

What am I missing here? I am finding it too difficult to understand why this prints `0` despite inheritance.

Comment: It prints 0 because you set x to 0 in the constructor. I honestly don't understand the question.

Comment: @sepp2k: ab is of type `class A`. `class A`'s `x` was only set to 10, and not to 0.

Comment: @sepp2k: I guess the OP thinks that the `x` that you access in `B` is different from the `x` in `A`, which is not the case.

Comment: @Lazer No, `ab` is of type `A *`. An the object is points to is actually of type `B`.

Comment: @delnan: yes I understand that. But I dont think that is related to my doubt here. I guess inheritance does not result in a new variable copy, that was what I was missing.

Comment: By the way, you have a memory leak in your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple figure that briefly explains inheritance in terms of member variables:

[image]

When the `ChildClass` is created, the `BaseClass` is created and exists inside the ChildClass. Variables `a`, `b` and `c` can be accessed from both `ChildClass` and `Baseclass` (depending on access modifiers such as public, private and protected). **They're shared, not copied**.

Comment: So, the `BaseClass` members in your example are shared, but it does exist as an independent class (in the sense that a `BaseClass*` can still point to it, and be unaware of existence of `ChildClass`). Interesting, and thanks!

Comment: Yes. However, you cannot point to a class, only to an object (an instance of the class).

Answer (score 1):

> I expected it to inherit a copy of member variable x

No, you don't inherit by copying.  `B` inheriting `A` results in every object of `B` containing a subobject of type `A`.  Since `x` is defined in `A`, you modify the `A` subobject by assigning to `x`.

The following reformulation of the code makes this subobject visible:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  int x;
  A() { x = 10; }
};

struct B {
  A subobject;
  B(): subobject() { this->subobject.x = 0; }
};

int main() {
  B* ab = new B;
  cout << ab->subobject.x << endl; // prints 0
}
```

This is of course not identical to inheritance since the types `A` and `B` are now not related any more (you cannot convert from `B` to `A`), but it is somewhat analogous to what the compiler sees when you use inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

`inherit a copy of member variable x` - well, it doesn't inherit a *copy*, it just inherits the variable. and it did.

First the constructor of `A` runs (x=10), the the constructor of `B` (x=0). After that, `x` is obviously `0`.

Based on your comment, I think your looking for *composition* and not *inheritance*:

```
class B {
   public:
     A a;
     int x;
};
```

Comment: but `class A`'s copy of `x` is still 10

Comment: there's only one `x`. and, *again*, *no* copying. check update.

Comment: @Lazer There are no member variables in a _class_, only in instantiated objects of the class! And in this case, there is only one object, hence, only one `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`B` inherits `x` from `A` (with the value 10 set in `A`'s constructor), but then immediately sets it to 0 in its own constuctor.

There is only one `x` shared by `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Or to put it another way, there is no implicit 0-ness or 10-ness to the member `x`. What happens, happens because you call the constructor of `B` with the `new` call. Whether the `x` is defined in `A` or in `B` or as a global variable, doesn't matter. The constructor of `B` sets it to 0, so it is 0.

Does this help?

Comment: It does matter, because if it was redefined in B, the value printed would have been 10.

Comment: Then the question would have been utterly different! I was trying to explain that it doesn't matter **where** `x` is defined. I was not saying it doesn't matter **how many** `x`s you have.